# how to convert javascript fetch to cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I want convert javascript fetch to cloudflare worker, But does cloudflare worker work with cookies?
I want to display a json file.

my javascript fetch code:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "session=MTY4Mzhsdhfksdhfkshdjk");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://example.com/list", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Or is there a code that logs in from Cloudflare worker and then accesses the JSON file?

Thank you friends.

‌‌‌‌‌‌ ‌‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌‌ ‌‌‌

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and time to embrace `let` and `const` while letting `var` retire. You should also be able to use `async` functions and `await` instead of the old chained `then` style.

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to achieve, if code works locally then it will work in workers, about logging from cloudflare docs https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/logging-workers/ it shows that you can get logs either from dashboard either via their "wrangler" utility

Comment: This code should work fine in Workers AFAICT. If you are having a problem, please be more specific about what's going wrong.